# Electron absorbtion properties

Tags: particle-physics, solid-state-physics, atomic-physics, physical-chemistry

Is it possible to predict the wave length of the electromagnetic radiation that will be emitted by a material when hit by a beam of electrons?

Comment: Einstein did this in 1905.

Comment: @my2cts are you referring to the photoelectric effect? I'm looking for a factor on which I can rely to predict the wavelength of the emitted radiation pretty much in all cases. I'm not sure if the photoelectric effect is what I am looking for.

Comment: Depends on the process(es) you wish to involve. But, for something like Bremsstrahlung there are expressions you can look up.

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks a lot for your comment.